# Conda package unavailable for my OS

Tags: python, package, anaconda, conda

I am trying to reproduce the results of someone else's Python code for a project. I have the entire setup - conda on my machine, the virtual environment .yml file, the relevant packages, and the data.

However, the code relies on one package from the conda repo that is only available for Linux, and not MacOS. I'm confused and I'm looking for any ways by which I could still use this package on my Mac. Googling doesn't seem to help. The package does have a gitlab page with the code given there, but I don't know how to use it. Any advice/help would be appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you should tell us which package it is.

Comment: My aplogies, this is the gitlab link to the package: https://gitlab.com/cheminfIBB/tfbio
Here's the conda link: https://anaconda.org/cheminfIBB/tfbio/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to try to install it using pip / pip3.

Create your conda environment, here's a random example:
`conda -create -n ENVIRONMENTNAME python=3.6 numpy pandas`
and then...

If you are using Python2:
`pip install tfbio`

If you are using Pyton3:
`pip3 install tfbio`

Comment: It doesn't create the conda environment from the .yml file because tfbio is is not present:

Sachitas-MacBook-Pro:~ sachita$ conda env create -f /Users/sachita/Documents/pafnucy_copy/environment_cpu.yml 
Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound: 
  - tfbio=0.3

Comment: Install tfbio manually and then simply remove it from the .yml
So it will be installed and working as a dependency but the .yml file will not complain about the impossibility to install it.

Comment: You can also install it manually cloning the repo locally, entering its folder and using "pip install ."

Comment: Just be sure that: 1) Activate conda env 2) install tfbio
You can create a conda env manually, install tfbio and then manually install all requirements in the YAML file, still manually.

Comment: When I clone the repo, enter it and run 'pip install', it gives me:
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tfbio (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tfbio

Comment: If you clone the repo you should use 'pip install .' from the repo folder

Comment: That didn't work, but pip install git+(link to repo) did! Now I need to figure out how to get the .yml file, since it gives me the same error

Comment: That is great!
Did you install it AFTER activating the conda env, right?
If so now you just need to manually install all the dependencies you find in the YAML file and the end result will be a full working environment.

Comment: I installed it outside the environment, just to see if it would work. Now I'll just do as you said. Is there a chance the tfbio package give me errors when I run my code, given that it was written for Linux?

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! I've been trying make-shift alternatives for days and I am so thankful for your help!

Comment: I am very happy to read it! If my answer helped you please upvote and / or choose it as answer @SachitaN